# Menu list item is considered as button by accessibility tool but it's not

Tags: html, accessibility

I tested my website with one of the accessibility tools. As the result it reported that my website menu is not compliant because:

> Elements that behave as buttons but are built using other tags such as span, div, a or others, should include a "role" attribute that equals to "button".

In fact, this is a general `<li>` tag that has no click actions or whatever.

```
  <div class="ch-wp-menu-item-dropdown-wrapper">
    <ul class="ch-wp-menu-item-dropdown">
      <li class="ch-wp-menu-item-dropdown-content">

        {% for subItem in item.values %}
        <div class="ch-wp-menu-item-subitem">
          <ul>
            <li class="ch-wp-menu-item-subitem-title" tabindex="0"> //the element that accessibility tool refers to
              {{subItem.name}}
            </li>
            {% for value in subItem.values %}
            <li>
              <a href="{{value.value}}"
                tabindex="0"
                aria-label="{{value.name}}">
                <div class="ch-wp-menu-item-subitem-record">{{value.name}}</div>
              </a>
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}

      </li>
      <div class="ch-wp-menu-item-dropdown-backdrop"></div>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Could you advise what might be the reason for this error?

Comment: I think it's the div embedded in the anchor tag.. that's a node behaving like a button not being a button and not having a role attribute

Comment: Please share your actual HTML code that the browser sees and displays, not whatever this is (PHP, I'm assuming).

Comment: Which accessibility tool were you using? The `<li>` that you flagged as causing the error doesn't have anything to indicate that it might be a button so I don't see why the tool thinks it's a button, unless there's something in the class `ch-wp-menu-item-subitem-title` causing it, but you didn't post your CSS. I also don't see a `role=menu` so the tool shouldn't find any submenu (button) issues either. I **do** see a `<div>` as a child of a `<ul>` (the last div), which is not valid HTML.

Comment: If the element isn't a button and if it isn't interactive in any way, why does it have tabindex=0 ? The focus shouldn't go to something that hasn't any interactive function.

Comment: Is there any JavaScript binding on the click event of the <a>? Does the validation change if you remove the redundant tabindex="0"?

Comment: Actually, I’m referring to the `<li>`: Does it have any event handlers attached? Why is there a tabindex="0"? That is what is causing the error. It’s role is `listitem`. While your error might go away if you set `role="menuitem"`, the whole construct around is missing, and will produce consequent errors then. See [ARIA menu role](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/menu_role)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your a tag to

```html
<a role="button" href="{{value.value}}" tabindex="0" aria-label="{{value.name}}">
    <div class="ch-wp-menu-item-subitem-record">{{value.name}}</div>
</a>
```

Note that the role attribute has now been set.